# Convert Python Bytes to String Without Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6 and I have an image as bytes:

```
img = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00'
```

I need to convert the bytes into a string without encoding so it looks like:

```
raw_img = '\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00'
```

The goal is to incorporate this into an html image tag:

```
<img src="'data:image/png;base64," + base64.b64encode(raw_img) + "' />"
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just call str and remove the b after?

In:

```
str(img)[2:-1]
```

Out:

```
'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00'
```

Comment: I'm also seeing that backslashes are being converted to double backslashes in the process

Comment: @slaw No they aren't.

Comment: That's the escape character...
In reality there is only one backslash. Because of stuff like \n being newline, another backslash is added to escape it. The raw string representation is still just one backslash.

Comment: repr(img) is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
img.decode("utf-8")
```

You can decode the variable with the above.  Then convert it to base64.

```
"<img src='data:image/png;base64,{}'/>".format( base64.b64encode(img.decode("utf-8")) )
```

UPDATED:

What you really want is this:

```
raw_img = repr(img)
"<img src='data:image/png;base64,{}'/>".format( base64.b64encode(raw_img) )
```

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: why someone downvoted me when I provided the correct answer is unfortunate.

Comment: Not the down-voter but I think it might because you used the wrong encoding.

Comment: It was downvoted within seconds of my post.  And I have since updated it with the resolution that address his expressed issue.

Comment: Yours was too, but I upvoted it because I thought it was unfair.

Comment: I get this: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: `img.encode("utf-8")` Or something similar to address that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you just need to convert the image to  string why not just use `str()` function?

```
>>> img = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00'
>>> type(img)
<class 'bytes'>
>>>
>>>raw_img = str(img)
>>> type(str(img)) 
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

`img` is in bytes, but when you use `str()` it is converted to type string.

An encoding can also be specified https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str, which would be a more natural way to do things:

```
str(img, encoding='ansi')
```

As suggested in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't solve this but here's some research on it(3Feb2022): This encoding is `latin` (or `latin-1`) and it's hard to print because Python wants to print it in another format. But for your case they should be the same. And for a `data:image/png;base64` base64 code should be used.

My test code:

```py
import codecs

img = b"\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00"
desired = "\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00"
str_decode = img.decode("latin-1")
str_decode_2 = str(img, "latin-1")
codecs_decode = codecs.decode(img, "latin-1")
print(desired.encode("latin-1") == img)
print(str_decode == desired)
print(str_decode == str_decode_2)
print(str_decode == codecs_decode)
print("desired:", repr(desired))  ##devprint
```

This gives 4 `True` and a `desired: ÿØÿà\x00\x10JFIF\x00` with Python 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it (2022 - bit late to the party...)
If you try img_raw.decode() you get the
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte` error

But if you leave `img_raw` as a binary string and pass it into `b64encode` and **then** decode it, it doesn't have the UnicodeDecodeError, and you can pass it in as a data string to your image tag.

`base64.b64encode(raw_image).decode()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `img` *is* the byte string that you want to pass to `base64.b64encode`:

```
>>> import base64
>>> img = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00'
>>> base64.b64encode(img)
b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA='
```

If you want to incorporate that into an HTML string, use

```
html = b'<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + base64.b64encode(img) + b' />'
```

Comment: Not quite. It still adds `b'` to the beginning of the string and `'` to the end but the image still doesn't show up

Comment: No, it doesn't; the `b` is just part of the *representation* of the value, not the value itself. Look at the result of `list(img)`. The value of `img` you posted doesn't seem to contain a complete image; it looks like just an image header.

Comment: This `"{}".format(base64.b64encode(img))` produces `"b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA='"`. Notice that the double quotes are around the `b'` which implies that it is being incorporated into the string.

Comment: OK, see pending update. I was apparently testing with a weird mix of Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: (I forgot to keep `bytes` and `str` objects distinct, and `bytes.format` isn't defined in Python 3.)